# Find words in an array in a specific order with indexes in Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd
data = {'token_1': [['cat', 'run','today'],['dog', 'eat', 'meat']],
        'token_2': [['cat', 'in', 'the' , 'morning','cat', 'run', 'today',
                      'very', 'quick', 'cat','today', 'jump', 'and', 'run', 'run', 'cat', 'today'],['dog', 'eat', 'meat', 'chicken', 'from', 'bowl','dog','see','meat','eat']],
       'token_pos':[[(0,'cat'), (2,'the') , (3,'morning'), (4,'cat'), (5,'run'), (6,'today'),
                      (7,'very'), (8,'quick'), (9,'cat'), (10,'today'), (12,'and'), (13,'run'), (14,'run'), (15,'cat'), (16,'today')],
                    [(0,'dog'), (1,'eat'), (2,'meat'), (3,'chicken'),(5,'bowl'),(6,'dog'),(7,'see'),(8,'meat'),(9,'eat'),(15,'bowl')]]]}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to find the words from the column `token_1` in `token_pos`, and in a **certain order**  and create `new_token`. Moreover, leave the numbers corresponding to these words. So it will be:

```
               new_token
0   [(4, cat), (5, run), (6, today)]
1   [(0, dog), (1, eat), (2, meat)]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using this for? This is a very unusual use of pandas. as you need to loop constantly you don't really take advantage of pandas vectorial power.

Comment: It's just that after some filtering, some words disappear, so I need to restore them. That's why order is so important to me. Because as you can see, the numbers are not all in order.

Comment: My question was more generic, what are you really doing with that? linguistics? something else?

Comment: Yes, I work with texts, so this applies to linguistics

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loops again, ideally building a dictionary of values (iterating in reverse to keep the first value as key):

```
dicts = [{t[1]: t for t in l[::-1]} for l in df['token_pos']]

df['new_token'] = [[d.get(x) for x in l] for d,l in zip(dicts, df['token_1'])]
```

output:

```
             token_1                                            token_2  \
0  [cat, run, today]  [cat, in, the, morning, cat, run, today, very,...   
1   [dog, eat, meat]  [dog, eat, meat, chicken, from, bowl, dog, see...   

                                           token_pos  \
0  [(0, cat), (2, the), (3, morning), (4, cat), (...   
1  [(0, dog), (1, eat), (2, meat), (3, chicken), ...   

                          new_token  
0  [(0, cat), (5, run), (6, today)]  
1   [(0, dog), (1, eat), (2, meat)]
```

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I would like to keep the order of tokens from the `token_1` column, i.e. here it will not be `(0, cat), (5, run), (6, today)`, but  `(4, cat), (5, run), (6, today)`

Comment: Haven't I already replied to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72786475/16343464)?

Comment: Yes, I know, thanks for that, but now I have a problem with adding numbers